# Application in asp.net slows down when a file is changed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

I have a problem with an old application in asp.net.
This application runs on a server with windows server 2012 and is used by hundreds of people at the same time (same app but which is pointed to by different domains).

The problem is this: every time I modify an .asp file, the page takes a lot of time to "recompile" the code and this causes damage to the users who use it.

This problem does not occur with the exact same application but running on another dedicated server used only by one user.

I've been researching for days, the only noteworthy thing found is that, in the server iis, if I recycle on application pool -> select the application, it has exactly the same effect.

I don't know much about windows server so I ask you for help.

Thank you!

Comment: There's not a lot of information to go on here. It sounds like you're not deploying a [Precompiled Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs), though, if it's recompiling on the server whenever you touch an .asp(x???) file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of deployment models.

First is what we call a asp.net web site,
and then second, is what we call a asp.net web site application.

They sound the same - but they are not.

So, while most perfer using a "application"? The ONE down side is that you have to re-publish the WHOLE site if you say change some code behind. This is good, and bad. The good part is that your code is re-compiled BEFORE you publish. (and in fact, you might even want to re-name "app_code", since that does re-compile by the web site.

However, for the most part a web applcation is "harder" to make a small update, since when you publish, you have to re-publish the whole site. But, the good part is that all code tends to be compiled down to ONE .dll. In effect the the site is pre-compiled before publishing. And with a applciaton, then you can add/change and do more things. In effect, the web site "applcation" allows you to do things like create say a custom logon provider. In most cases, this means the WHOLE site is under your developer control. It also means that code behind (source code) is NOT pushed up to the site.

Then you have what is called a asp.net web site. This allows you to say modify the code (code behind) of one page and then push that one page (and code) up to the site. The web site will thus re-compile that one page. You will note the "delay" that you experiance - but it ONLY occures the first time that page is published.

So, for a "application", you will in Visual Studio open up the project (and a sln file) is used.

For a web site, you from Visual Studio go open->web site.

I hands down prefer web applications, but they are MUCH harder to deploy a small change, since as noted, you have to re-publish the whole site.

However, the two different choices would thus explain the "difference" and as to why the other site don't experience the delay as much as you are. However, usually on first load - there can be a one time delay after a re-publish. And this quite much means the site is down for this time to re-publish.

Also, do keep in mind that if you do modify some files (such as web config), then this WILL cause the app-pool to re-start. (and if you not using sql server sessions, but in-memory sessions - they get blown out when you do this).

It also somewhat possible that the server with one user has more memory, more CPU and a much lighter load - so the reduced delay after making changes might well be the light load on that server.

However, the above two different publishing models and types of asp.net sites would be the first thing or at least the first issue to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to determine if it is a website or web application project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd547590(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Anchor_1). Default for web application is rebuild for single page changes while default for website does not force recompilation except if special folders or files are modified. You may check to see if any settings for the app pool differ-- in particular "Disable Overlapping Recycle". You may also check the web.config as there may be a setting that is forcing rebuild. You want also want to look at Explicit Complication/pre-compilation option.

You may want to reference the following resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/determining-what-files-need-to-be-deployed-cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd547590(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Anchor_1

Optimization setting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidebb/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior